# ERROR: ld.so: object '/opt/xyz/mylib.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored

Tags: c++, ld-preload

After upgrading a software from 32 to 64-bit, a pre-compiled binary starts to fail with the error:

```
[root@localhost /root]# LD_PRELOAD=/opt/xyz/lib/mylib.so mycommand /inputfile.txt /outputfile.txt 
ERROR: ld.so: object '/opt/xyz/lib/mylib.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
mycommand: error while loading shared libraries: mylib.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

`mycommand` is a precompiled binary that sits in /usr/bin/mycommand. It requires the library as LD_PRELOAD.

Obviously I made sure that the file /opt/xyz/lib/mylib.so does exist:

```
[root@localhost lib]# ls -alh
total 512K
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Mar  1 15:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 4.0K Feb 24 10:54 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 218K Oct 28 22:41 mylib64.so
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   14 Mar  1 15:40 mylib.so -> mylib64.so
```

Is there any more debugging information I can extract other that this error?
It seems like not relevant if I simply delete the mylib.so or not, the error stays the same. It's kind of hard to say if it can't *preload* the library or if it can't *find* the library.

Is there any other environment variables or libraries that are required for LD_PRELOAD to work?

It seems to me essential to acquire a version of the source code of the mycommand binary and re-compile it. However to do that I think it would be probably useful to see why it actually fails right now.

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)

Comment: Not sure if it applies here, but did you run `ldconfig` (as root) after installing the library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LD_PRELOAD will not work on symlinks. You will need to set the path to the actual location of the library. For example:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/opt/xyz/lib/mylib64.so
```

I agree that a more specific error message would've been useful.